# Using a loop to impute dataframes with mice, using prediction matrices from a list

Tags: r, for-loop, apply, r-mice

I have a global environment with many dataframes which should be imputed with mice `library(mice)`. In order to first calculate the prediction matrices I did (with the help of some other people) the following:

```
library(mice)
PredMatr= list()
Myls<-ls(sorted=F)[eapply(.GlobalEnv, class)=="data.frame"]
try (for (i in 1:length(Myls))  {
    PredMatr[[i]]=quickpred(get(Myls[i]), mincor=.1)
})
```

This creates a very nice list with all the prediction matrices. The next step however is even a bit more complicated. I would like to do something similar to do the imputation. I want to loop through the dataframes like before. However now I would like the operation to be an imputation, referring to the predictor matrix from the previous list. I tried:

```
dfimpls= list()
try (for (i in 1:length(Myls))  {
    dfimpls[[i]]=mice(get(Myls[i]), m=5, maxit = 5, method='cart',predictorMatrix=PredMatr[i])
})
```

The syntax is however incorrect, giving me the following error:

```
Error : predictorMatrix not a matrix
```

With:

```
dfimpls= list()
try (for (i in 1:length(Myls))  {
    dfimpls[[i]]=mice(get(Myls[i]), m=5, maxit = 5, method='cart',predictorMatrix=as.matrix(PredMatr[i]))
})
```

I get:

```
Error : Missing row/column names in predictorMatrix
```

Comment: is `PredMatr[i]` a `matrix` or `data.frame`? If you just change it to `predictorMatrix=as.matrixPredMatr[i])` does that help?

Comment: Please show us data of underlying data frames so we can reproduce your issue as required by a [MCVE]. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: It should really be a matrix.. I added you suggestion to the answer (although it probably only applies if `PredMatr[i]` was not a matrix but a df right?)

Comment: @JohnPaul Is it possible that it is again an ordering issue? In other words, that the list of prediction matrices `PredMatr` is in a different order than the `Myls` ?

Comment: @Tom You should check to make sure that the column names in the `PredMatr`s are the same as those expected by `mice()`. If the names are different it might not now how to do the prediction - but  I am not familiar with this package.

Comment: A question: Why do you need a prediction matrix for Mice? I thought mice imputation is just as simple as `mice(df)`.

Comment: @CoreyLevinson https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/sec-toomany.html

Comment: Have you tried `predictorMatrix=PredMatr[[i]]`?

Comment: @ Ian Wesley That actually worked, thank you so much!